# Moving all the particles in effect LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

I have a few particle effects that I would like to be in a circle shape
in libgdx i.e. not a cone shape. I have done this by setting the direction
of the particle effect from 0 to 360. The problem is that the particle effect
is moving. So, as the emitters are moving, but not the particles themselves,
the overall shape becomes conical. This could simply resolved by moving all the
particles along with the particle emitters, but I can't fnd any way of doing
this. I have considered drawing the effect to a Frame Buffer Object in one
position, then draw the texture to each new position. However, this would mean I would have to flush the SpriteBatch each time a draw a particle effect, and that would be very expensive.

Is there any  way to move the entire effect, with both the emitters and the particles?

Thannks in advance

Comment: 2D or 3D effects?

Comment: I think there is a parameter called attached which defines if the particle are attached to the emitters. There is a reference list on https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/particle-effects-libgdx-2d/